# passenger not spawning minimum no of instances process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

On restart of apache it start the minimum no of instances. But after sometime the instances reduces to less than minimum no of instances. Also i start getting randomly 500 errors on my application. I am assuming that some of the passenger process has been killed but not restarted which is causing error.
My settings

PassengerMaxPoolSize 40

PassengerMaxPoolSize 20

My passenger status shows

max      = 40

count    = 4

active   = 0

inactive = 4

Waiting on global queue: 0

The count is always less than minimum instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on Phusion Passenger 3, which is over 2 years old. Try Phusion Passenger 4, which fixes many resource control related issues.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to upgrade and check.